# Getting error like weblogic.home env variable must be set to create osb12 config jar while executing ant script Following is the script I am using

Tags: ant

**config.xml (build file)**

Ant script to create An Oracle Service Bus Config Jar from file system.

```
<target name="run">

    <taskdef name="configjar" classname="com.bea.alsb.tools.configjar.ant.ConfigJarTask"/>
    <property name="task.failonerror"               value="true" />
    <property name="task.errorproperty"             value="" />
    <property name="settingsFile" value="C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb\tools\configjar\config.xml"/>


     <property name="WL_HOME"      value="C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver" />
     <property name="MW_HOME"            value="C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\" />
     <property name="OSB_HOME"           value="C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\osb" />

    <!--configjar failonerror="${task.failonerror}" errorProperty="${task.errorproperty}" settingsFile="${settingsFile}" -->


    <configjar settingsFile="${settingsFile}" >

    </configjar>
</target>
```

**my settings file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configjarSettings xmlns="http://www.bea.com/alsb/tools/configjar/config">
    <source>
    <project dir="D:\JDeveloper\mywork\ServiceBusApplication2" />
        <!--extensionMapping>
            <mapping type="str1234" extensions="str1234" />
            </extensionMapping-->
    <!--fileset>
            <include name="str1234" />
            <exclude name="str1234" />
    </fileset-->
</source>
<configjar jar="SBProject.jar" overwrite="false">
    <projectLevel includeSystem="true">
        <project>SBProject</project>
    </projectLevel>
</configjar>
</configjarSettings>
```

I have set weblogic environment variable on command prompt , globally using environment variable section of Windows but still not luck.

I am stuck at this point.Need solution on the same.

I am using soa12c.And this is osb script for creation of configuration jar file for osb application.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `D:\Oracles\Middleware12c\osb\tools\configjar` and run `setenv.cmd`. On the same cmd try running your ant script. It might ask for `MW_HOME`, set that also.